# hibernateTemplate, entityInterceptor with state and threading

Tags: hibernate, spring

I have an interceptor for audit-logging that basically sets two fields modified_by and created_by. For example,

```
public void update(DomainEntity entity, Integer userId) {
    template.update(audited(entity, userId));
}

private DomainEntity audited(DomainEntity entity, Integer userId) { 
    template.setEntityInterceptor(new AuditInterceptor(userId));
    return entity;
}
```

So I create a new Interceptor with the userId in question and set it on the template for each auditable DAO-operation. I am worried that there is a concurrency issue her, in that two threads may set the interceptor on the same template, messing things up.

What is the best solution to avoid this ? the userId is state that the interceptor needs to know about. Any alternative designs ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a servlet filter store the userid in a ThreadLocal, and let the interceptor use that.

Comment: Not in servlet-land, unfortunately.... each request contains a session identifier which the server uses to look up the userid. So requests from the same user will be handled by different threads

Comment: @ThuneGill: it's the same concept, though, isn't it? You have some front-controller thing that looks up the userid.

Answer (score 1):

@nathan presented an advanced approach.  If you want a simpler alternative, why not have one generic interceptor, that looks up based on a Map of auditable classes, an appropriate delegate.  The delegates would all share a common interface that the generic interceptor is aware of.  If you avoid state in your generic interceptor, you have no threading concerns.  Also, like your current approach, you can unit test the interceptors in isolation.